How to populate with final string value instead of nested object in mongodb?
How should i populate a field with string value instead of nested object?
Here is the code i am currently using to populate-
  const voucherNoFoundResponse = await StockOrder.findOne({_id: voucherID})
    .populate({
        path: 'entries.item',
        select: 'desc.name -_id',
    }).lean()

But this is giving me this nested object -
voucherNoFoundResponse.entries[0].item.desc.name

How should i trim the fat and get the final result as a string inside voucherNoFoundResponse.entries[0].item

You would need to use Model.aggregate() so that you can transform the document shape with $project instead of findOne().populate() which is purely for simplicity. Otherwise its a basic JavaScript function that can do it. You would need to share your schema and two sample MongoDB documents that work just now with the populate.
